# trigger.io toolkit dies when uploading private module

Tags: python, ios, trigger.io

I'm getting an error when trying to upload a custom module for a trigger app. I'm not sure what's going on; it looks like maybe a bad response a badly formatted json.

```
Error in remote call to api.post_files: Forge API call to module/admob/version went wrong: Expecting object: line 9 column 1 (char 174)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevzettler/Library/Trigger Toolkit/build-tools/forge/async.py", line 106, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/kevzettler/Library/Trigger Toolkit/trigger/api/api.py", line 20, in post_files
    return forge_tool.singleton.remote._api_post(method, data=data, cookies=cookies, files=opened_files)
  File "/Users/kevzettler/Library/Trigger Toolkit/build-tools/forge/remote.py", line 475, in _api_post
    _check_api_response_for_error(url, 'POST', resp)
  File "/Users/kevzettler/Library/Trigger Toolkit/build-tools/forge/remote.py", line 121, in _check_api_response_for_error
    _raise_if_json_error(content_dict, error_template, resp, url)
  File "/Users/kevzettler/Library/Trigger Toolkit/build-tools/forge/remote.py", line 81, in _raise_if_json_error
    raise RequestError(resp, error_message, errors=errors)
RequestError: Forge API call to module/admob/version went wrong: Expecting object: line 9 column 1 (char 174)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the content of your config_schema.json file is invalid.

Unfortunately the error message you see isn't very useful. The good news is newer platform versions have better validation of local files before upload, so if you develop your module against a newer platform version errors like this should be listed in the Toolkit before upload.